# How to choose some value based on condition from appended list?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I want to choose an optimal threshold which maximises accuracy. Using for loop, I found and appended to the list all the values of accuracy and could print and see which threshold is optimal for maximum accuracy. However, I would like to make a code that will output only the maximum accuracy and its threshold OR that will take separately the maximum accuracy and its threshold under variables.

```
lm__pred_train = lm_.predict(X_train)

def fn_accuracy(actuals, predictions):
    return np.mean(actuals == predictions)

thresholds = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)

accuracy = []
for th in thresholds:
    acc = np.round(fn_accuracy(lm__pred_train > th, y_train), 3)
    accuracy.append(acc)
    print(th, acc)
```

I'm kinda of newb and so far get lost in for loop thus will really appreciate any help on my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lm__pred_train = lm_.predict(X_train)

def fn_accuracy(actuals, predictions):
    return np.mean(actuals == predictions)

thresholds = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)

accuracy = []
max_acc=0
max_th=threshold[0]
for th in thresholds:
    acc = np.round(fn_accuracy(lm__pred_train > th, y_train), 3)
    accuracy.append(acc)
    if acc>max_acc:
        max_acc=acc
        max_th=th

print(max_th, max_acc)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Mark this answer as accepted so that other people will not try to answer the question.